# How to start a clientTask from within a ServerTask in Android?

Tags: android

I have a client-server app, where each app has both client-server functionalities.

The client in one app sends a number, to which the server side on the second app has to reply. To reply, I need to start a client Task to do it. But I get the error "Method executeOnExecutor must be called from the main thread, currently inferred thread is worker".

I cannot show the exact code, so I am posting some psuedo code for better explanation :

```
private class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<ServerSocket, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ServerSocket... sockets) {

      ...receive from client.. do processing. need to reply
      new ClientTaskName.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,message);

    }         
 }

 private class ClientTaskName extends  AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Message... params) {
        //... do something...
        return null;
    }

 }
```

If I am not allowed to create a clientTask from within the serverTask, what are my options ?

EDIT:

I am adding a basic overall process flow:

1. Process A send msg1 to process B.
2. Process B receives it in ServerTask, **replies** to it
3. Process A receives the reply, decides some additional parameters based on the reply, sends ACK with the decided parameter.
4. Process B receives ACK and configures its own future messages with received parameter.

This requires that the ServerTask handle two types of messages in its doInBackground function, one where it expects only ACK, and one where it will reply to the received message.

The steps 1-4 will run arbitrary number of times.

SDK used : API 19

Comment: can't you start it from onPostExecute?

Comment: @Blackbelt : No I cant. I added basic process flow to explain why

Comment: Do you need runOnUiThread ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Use threads instead of AsyncTasks.

That is how it is normally done.